# Should a web service log response data (if yes, on which level)?

Tags: java, web-services, logging

The RESTful service in response body returns `List<User>`, where

```
public class User {
    private String id;
    private List<String> roles;

    // constructor, getters, toString() are snipped    
}
```

I am struggling to decide whether `List<User>` should be logged in the service. On the one hand, logging the data might be helpful to find cause of error in production. On the other hand, "noise" in logs and performance impact of I/O operations should be taken into account. What would be the best practice to log the mentioned list of users? (Should it be logged completely? Only its `.length()`? And what logging level would be better to use?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to log users or their roles, you might want to log information that would give you directions to get better performance and later on modifications and optimizations of the code.
for the levels, if you are using LOG4J, you might want to use ERROR and WARN, INFO and DEBUG are secondary. 
Here is [a link for best practices to log in java](https://www.loggly.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/loggly_ebook_Pragmatic_Handbook_online.pdf) but you might want to check the internet, i think there is enough information for you to make an optimal logging strategy.

PS: i'm not familiar yet with GDPR policies, but if you are in europe or else ,you might want to check your continent policies, because logging users and their preferences and roles etc ... without their direct consent might be out of the law. [This link](https://logsentinel.com/gdpr-practical-guide-developers/) might give you an idea of what are the best practices to log the necessary data without getting out of the law.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. In this case it depends on what would be a typical size of `List<User>`, is it 10s? 1000s? It also depends on the `User` object, does it contain large number of fields including other objects?

Generally you can always log the size of a list. And if you decide to log the content, it should be in `DEBUG` level. Additionally, you can override `toString()` in `User` to output a more compact string representation.